# Exclude multiple folders with Dir command

Tags: batch-file, dir

I had search thru the forum with excluding multiple files while using DIR command. But didn't find what i really needed. Some are even with PHP or VBS, really don't know how they works.

What I'm trying to do is **DIR*ing* all profile folders and also excluding certain default folders, this is a part of showing what and how many users are having profiles on that computer.

I will explain a bit more because i may not fully be understood what my needs are.

If i use the *DIR* without *findstr*.

```
DIR /A:d /B "F:\Documents and Settings"
```

Output:

```
Administrator
All Users
Default User
LocalService
userprofile1
NetworkService
userprofile2
...
userprofileN
```

But my actual needs are:

```
userprofile1
userprofile2
...
userprofileN
```

I also got this far with my script now.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO Your OS does not support enable extensions
DIR /A:d /B "F:\Documents and Settings" | findstr /v "Admin" | findstr /v "Default" | findstr /v "LocalService" | findstr /v "NetworkService"
EXIT
```

My above script actually works but is fixed and may not be pretty coded.
I would ask about is it possible to use a *For* loop to shorten the long *findstr* pipes and set a variable that contains the folder names to exclude ?
I prefer to use a variable instead of a text files that contains folders to exclude.

I came up with below but it duplicates the ouput:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO Your OS does not support enable extensions
SET xUser="Admin" "Default" "hi_I_will_be_future_added"
FOR %%A IN (!Xuser!) DO ( 
 DIR /A:d /B "F:\Documents and Settings" | findstr /v %%A
)
```

Thank you to this great forum and for all that may had helped both me and others.

Comment: `DIR /A:d /B "F:\Documents and Settings\userprofile*"` ?

Comment: I'm sorry with the userprofile1-N, it's just a dummy name. And if all users are named like that your script may actually work. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Oops! I am _very_ visual when I read the descriptions! For example, the `DIR` command shows the full path of the user profiles, but you said "my actual needs are:" and show _just the profiles_ so, do you want to remove the path or not? `;-)`. See my answer below...

Comment: Thanks, i will test it. After a few days i will be back and post the results. The idea with using if compare condition, looks very clean. Nice nice and thanks thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set exclude=/Administrator/All Users/Default User/LocalService/NetworkService/
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('DIR /A:d /B "F:\Documents and Settings"') do (
   if "!exclude:/%%~Na/=!" equ "%exclude%" echo %%a
)
```

If you want to show the user name only (with no "F:\Documents and Settings" path), use `echo %%~Na`

Comment: Powerful !! I could never do codes likes this, these are too complicated. And also something that i have dream about with the For..loop, Thanks Aacini.

Comment: You may review a detailed explanation of this method here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139331/if-else-condition-in-batch-file/24142847#24142847

Comment: Thanks, had tested it on Windows XP. It worked like a charm, but I'm a bit curious about "echo %%~Na" because it is already echoing only the user profile name(which I prefer).

Answer (score 3):

```
F:\>dir /AD /B "c:\documents and settings"| FINDSTR /V "All Default Local Networ
k"
Admin
Administrator

F:\>
```

Comment: Ally, Allycia, Allyn, Allison, Allyson?

Comment: Hmm, but actually this is what i thought about also without the For...loop. Didn't know that i could do this with one FINDSTR command.

Answer (score 2):

Splitted in several lines for better reading, but, of course, it can be in a single line

```
@echo off
    dir /ad /b "c:\Documents And Settings" ^
    | findstr /l /i /x /v   ^
        /c:"Administrator"  ^
        /c:"All Users"      ^
        /c:"Default User"   ^
        /c:"LocalService"   ^
        /c:"NetworkService"
```

Or, instead of passing all the strings as `/c:"..."` arguments, you can generate a file with all the strings to exclude and use the `/g:filename` switch of findstr