# If-else condition in batch file

Tags: c, windows, batch-file

I need to convert next code (C language) condition to batch file:

```
if(version == 1 || version == 2)
{
   // do something
}
else
{
   // do something other
}
```

So in batch file it will be looks like:

```
if "%version%"==1 (
 // do something
)
if "%version%"==2 (
 // do something
)
if not "%version%"==1 (
   // do something other
)
if not "%version%"==2 (
   // do something other
)
```

Is there more better way to write it?

Comment: That is an incorrect functional batch file representation of the C code. For example, if `%version%` is `1`, then you'll do both "do something" and "do something other".

Answer (score 1):

"There is no logic and/or but you can use the mighty goto.

```
if "%version%"=="1" goto :TRUE
if "%version%"=="2" goto :TRUE
REM do something else

echo neither 1 or 2 :(
goto :eof

:TRUE 
REM do something
echo 1 or 2 :)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set wantedVersions=/1/2/

if "!wantedVersions:/%version%/=!" neq "%wantedVersions%" (
   echo Version %version% is 1 or 2, do something
) else (
   echo Version %version% is NOT 1 or 2, do something other
)
```

This expression: `"!wantedVersions:/%version%/=!"` means: "In wantedVersion eliminate the string "/%version%/"; this way if version is 1 or 2, that value will be eliminated and the result will be different than the original => version is 1 or 2. The slashes are needed to avoid the false identification of version=12.

Yes, I know this method seems complicated, but it is simpler than the other options. Just try to imagine how the other options should be if you have 3 different values, or 4... Also, this method may be nested inside other IF/FOR commands with no problems.

Comment: @MCND: Of course, the delimiter must be choosen as a character that does not appear in the value...

Answer (score 0):

Another way with the same philosophy as @Aacini's answer

```
@ECHO OFF
set /p $var=version ? : 

set "$version=[1] [2]"
echo %$version% | find "[%$var%]" && echo do something || echo do something else
```

Comment: Same problem that Aacini's answer. `set "$var=1] [2"`

Comment: Is that really a problem in this case. The OP have the answer. But you're right this situation have to be considareted.